# Why This Java Code Use BuffedReader different from String split \r\n

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader

I have this below plain text stored as txt file in disk

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     93 3.505189000    192.168.1.125         204.79.197.200        HTTP     1160   GET /fd/ls/l?IG=C0F1A7E0A49E484DA6CAC4FA64BE2415&Type=Event.CPT&DATA={%22pp%22:{%22S%22:%22L%22,%22FC%22:12,%22BC%22:416,%22H%22:459,%22BP%22:647,%22CT%22:655,%22IL%22:8},%22ad%22:[-1,-1,1349,640,1349,1759,1]}&P=SERP&DA=Co3b HTTP/1.1

Frame 93: 1160 bytes on wire (9280 bits), 1160 bytes captured (9280 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: HonHaiPr_8c:81:48 (e0:06:e6:8c:81:48), Dst: Nintendo_ce:a4:2d (00:22:aa:ce:a4:2d)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.125 (192.168.1.125), Dst: 204.79.197.200 (204.79.197.200)
    Host: cn.bing.com\r\n
    Accept: image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.154 Safari/537.36 LBBROWSER\r\n
    Referer: http://cn.bing.com/search?q=wireshark%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E8%A7%86%E9%A2%91&go=%E6%8F%90%E4%BA%A4&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=wireshark%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E8%A7%86%E9%A2%91&sc=2-13&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=6AAF0CC941DB44F2AFA26B89D6E6ABF6\r\n
```

when I use BuffeRedreader to deal with this file,I want to get rid of '\r\n' and write the new txt without '\r\n' into new file.

Code like this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/wiresharkpack/a.txt"));
        String line = "";
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/wiresharkpack/rlt/a.txt"));
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line.replaceAll("\r\n", " "));
            bw.write(line+"\\r\\n");
            bw.newLine();
        }
```

But the result is that '\r\n' is still here.

I tried to get deal with this in String.
like this

```
  String lines = "http://b2.bst.126.net/newpage/r/c/c.css?v=1458632076134\r\n123"; 

     System.out.println(lines);
     //String[] arr = Pattern.compile("[\r\n]+|[\n\r]+|[\n]+").split(lines.trim());
     String[] arr = lines.split("\r\n");

     System.out.println();
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }
```

the result is that '\r\n' is no longer in the result.

With variable string ,'\r\n' can escape,while in files ,can not. So confused

Comment: When you add the `\r\n` it appears and when you don't add this, it doesn't appear, so what is the confusion?

Comment: Thanks for your revise!

Comment: It's not clear what your code is trying to do. Are you trying to add `\r\n` or just copy the input to the output?  BTW In both cases you are possibly changing the newline used. Is that deliberate?

Comment: I want to get rid of '\r\n' from the plain text and then  write the new without '\r\n' result into a new txt

Comment: In that case, `br.readLine()` discards the newlines.

Comment: @JohnRene If you truly want to get rid of `\r\n`, as you just said, then you'll end up with all lines concatenated together to a single very long line. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Andreas I want to get the result like ' Host: cn.bing.com' . The original line contains '\r\n' in the end in plain text.

Comment: @JohnRene And `readLine()` has removed them for you. What is you problem? You are writing `\\r\\n` followed by `newLine()`, so you get double newlines. Because *you* did that! As for your second example, `split()` removed the newlines, and `println()` added them again on your output, so you still have newlines in the output. Nothing removed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to know why this works `String lines = "http://b2.bst.126.net/newpage/r/c/c.css?v=1458632076134\r\n123"; 
String[] arr = lines.split("\r\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }`

Comment: @JohnRene when you use use `\r` or `\n` inside a String in Java it translates the two characters into a single character. When you have `\ ` and `r` that is two characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you are trying remove the string `\r\n` which is *four* characters in your input, not the `\r\n` which is two characters.

e.g.

```
String s = "Host: cn.bing.com\r\n";
String s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");
System.out.println(s2);
```

prints

```
Host: cn.bing.com
```

In short, you have an `\` (back slash) then `r` then `\` then `n` not the `\r` (return) and `\n` (new line) characters.

Comment: Oh~ I See that! Thanks @Peter Lawrey

Answer (score 1):

Your code with comments:

```
// Use try-with-resources
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/wiresharkpack/a.txt"));

 // No need to initialize. It's wasteful and misleading.
String line = "";

// Use try-with-resources
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/wiresharkpack/rlt/a.txt"));

while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){

    // readLine() has already removed the \r\n, no need for the replaceAll()
    System.out.println(line.replaceAll("\r\n", " "));

    // You are specifically adding \r\n, so why are you confused to see them in the output?
    bw.write(line+"\\r\\n");

    // You are specifically writing a newline, so why are you confused to see double in the output?
    bw.newLine();
}
```

Your code should be:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/wiresharkpack/a.txt"));
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/wiresharkpack/rlt/a.txt"))) {
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
      bw.write(line);
      bw.newLine(); // Remove to get rid of all \r\n in output
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.replaceAll()` creates a new String, so `line` is not changed.
You have to do

```
line = line.replaceAll();
```

to change line.

Comment: Very true, but besides the point for this particular example, because `readLine()` has already removed `\r\n`, so there is nothing to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove this line from the first solution.

```
bw.write(line+"\\r\\n");
```

That should do the trick on your first solution.

Also, remove this...

```
bw.newLine();
```

From the docs:

newLine
public void newLine()
             throws IOException
Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character.
Throws:
IOException - If an I/O error occurs

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

Comment: Oh This line should be bw.write(line).My mistake,when remove this ,line variable still contain '\r\n' . Sorry for my poor english

Comment: The bw.newLine() method is suspect here.

Comment: @JohnRene `line` variable never contains `\r\n`. `readLine()` has already removed them.